# CSS Media Query overriding prior styles in mobile first

Tags: css, overriding, media-queries

So this question seems to be asked a lot but in the reverse.. I'm having the issue where my media query is overriding the previously set styles in a mobile first design and I don't know why. Mobile should be `padding: 33rem 0` and desktop should be padding: `18rem`. See below.

```
.description {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#b676fa,#14D8EB);
    padding: 33rem 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .description {
        padding: 18rem;
    }

}
```

Comment: As a heads up, in your CodePen link, your `viewport` meta tag has the wrong quote marks wrapping the values. You have fancy quotes. That may be why you're seeing an issue in your browser. Your media query works fine in your CodePen link `<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1″>` should be `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.. All brackets closed? Run it through a CSS validator perhaps -   https://codepen.io/pmackey-deveire/pen/vYBvxQz

Have you checked the inspector to see what styles are being applied as you change the window size?

Perhaps using PX instead of REM for testing.. 33rem appears to be smaller than 18rem on mobile so you might be tricked into thinking it's not working

Comment: yes - inspector shows 'padding: 33rem 0" as crossed out when I check mobile and the overriding item is the padding: 18rem from the media query. if I uncheck that, it's fine.

Comment: Hmm, works fine in the codepen, unless there's a conflict somewhere else..

Comment: I'll upload to codepen and post link here so you can look at full code..

Comment: So on the codepen there, `description` is coming in at  `padding: 10rem 0 10rem;` and on mobile padding comes in at `padding: 33rem 0;` seems to be working as designed :/ https://codepen.io/rachel-campbell/full/vYBvxPV

I'm using Chromes responsive mode to change the breakpoints

Comment: Wish I could show screenshots.. it works on codepen for me too (of course, after I changed other things so the wide padding looks ridiculous on mobile..).... but when I load the file into chrome it's not showing up. I wonder if it has something to do with the font awesome icon I hid from codepen but is in the original file.. that's the only difference (I did change the 10rem to 18 0 18 to correct for adding the logo image which threw things off, but that didn't have any effect on the brokenness of chrome for me).

Comment: Think you have your answer above ^^, fancy quotes messing with your behaviour

Comment: ok so on chrome for me.. it's working if I manually change the screen size but if I hit the icon to toggle between devices it doesn't work there? Is this a chrome inspector issue?

Comment: It could be a browser issue, I'd suggest using something like BrowserStack.. Can be more reliable at times..